# I know you can nest an IfElse statement in a ForEach loop, but is the opposite also possible?

Tags: string, powershell, null, is-empty

Been using Powershell on and off for years but haven't really gotten into that much automation until now.  What I'm trying to accomplish is running a statement based on input for a variable.  Each statement will run just fine by itself.  The ELSE part of the test will run just fine with input from the variable.  However...the issue comes in with trying to run the first statement based on the default input for the variable.  This is for verifying proxy settings for users based on machine name.  I would like to use the same script to search/output either a single machine or from a list, depending on the input received.

I've tried everything I can think of and everything I can find on the internet.  I have a suspicion that I am missing something simple.  When I run the whole thing without the ErrorAction, it will run the ELSE statement with no issues if I enter a value into the prompt.  However...if I accept the default value (hasn't mattered what I put in there and have tried multiple iterations of values) it just skips directly to the ELSE statement and errors out since there isn't an input (no computer name to search on).

Here is the code as written:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$pathHKU = 'HKU:\.Default\Environment\'
$pathExists = Test-Path -Path $pathHKU

If(!($pathExists))
{ 
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_Users
}

$defaultValue = ""

$preSID = "Get-ItemPropertyValue 'registry::HKU\"
$postSID = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name ProxyServer"
$promptOutput = Read-Host "Press enter to search by list or type in the name of a single machine [$($defaultValue)]"
IF($null -eq $promptOutput) {
    $sysName | Add-Content -Path ".\testlist.txt"
ForEach ($sys in $sysName)
    {
        $SID = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $sys -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username | ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value}}
        $searchProxy = $preSID+$SID+$postSID
        $scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($searchProxy)
            ForEach ($script in $scriptBlock) {
                $userProxy = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $sys -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
            }
        $sys+" - "+$userProxy | Out-File -Path ".\TestProxySettings.csv" -Append
    }
}else{
    $nameComp = $promptOutput
    $SID = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameComp -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username | ForEach-Object { ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$_).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value}}
    $searchProxy = $preSID+$SID+$postSID
    $scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($searchProxy)
        ForEach ($script in $scriptBlock) {
            $userProxy = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nameComp -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
$nameComp+" - "+$userProxy
        }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: As soon as you enter _anything_ (including just hitting [ENTER] without writing any characters), `Read-Host` will return a string, and `$null -eq $promptOutput` will evaluate to false (an empty string is _not_ the same as `$null`). If you're trying to catch _empty_ strings, do `if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($promptOutput)) { ... }`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.  I also had my .txt file as Add-Content and had to change it to Get-Content and remove the pipe in order for it read properly, but now the script is working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `$promptOutput` contains the output from a [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Read-Host) call:

> `if ($null -eq $promptOutput) { ... }`

is *never* `$true`, because **`Read-Host` returns the *empty string*, not `$null`, when the user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>**.

Therefore, use:

```bash
if ('' -eq $promptOutput) { ... }
```

Or, given that the empty string is implicitly `$false` in a Boolean context such as an `if` conditional, you can use:

- `if (-not $promptOutput) { ... }`
  If you additionally want to also treat *blank* (all-whitespace) output the same as *empty* input:
- `if (-not $promptOutput.Trim()) { ... }`

In cases where the value's type isn't known in advance and may actually be `$null` or a different type, simply enclose the value in `"..."` to coerce it to a string first:

- `if (-not "$unknownValue") { ... }` to match `$null` or the empty string (equivalent of `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`)
- `if (-not "$unknownValue".Trim()) { ... }` to match `$null`, the empty string, or blank (all-whitespace) strings (equivalent of `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`).

---

Note that **PowerShell by design *in general* doesn't store `$null` in `[string]`-typed variables**: even when explicitly assigning `$null` it stores `''` (the empty string) instead:

```bash
# Despite assigning $null, it is '' (empty string) that is stored.
[string] $str = $null; $null -eq $str # !! $false
```

While there is a workaround for storing actual `$null`, using the `[NullString]::Value` singleton, its use is best avoided, except for what it was designed for: passing a true `$null` to `[string]`-typed *.NET method parameters*.